# tuple with get<U> but U is a derived class of a tuple type

Tags: c++, c++11, tuples

Suppose we have `std::tuple<Ts*...> tuple;`.  One of the types is `T*` and a class `U` derives from `T` (polymorphically).  How do we define

```
template <typename U> T* get(const std::tuple<Ts*...>&);
```

so that `get<U>(tuple)` returns `std::get<T*>(tuple)`?  Of course, we want `get<T>(tuple)` to return `std::get<T*>(tuple)`.

Comment: Tuples aren't pointers. They don't (and can't) store instances of subclasses. If you tried to put a `U` into a tuple position expecting a `T`, then it stopped being a `U` the moment you did so due to [object slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-object-slicing).

Comment: Is this a typo? I'd expect the opposite, getting a reference to base when the tuple stores a derived class.

Comment: Sorry, the types in question are all pointers.  I'll edit my question.

Comment: you could start from libc++'s [implementation](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/d4a8a59441052165ccdd6ca493ce124be5e80d9e/libcxx/include/tuple#L1416) and change `std::is_same` to `std::is_base_of`

Comment: If you have a base class getting a pointer to a derived class out of it has approximately zero chances of success, irrespective of whether a tuple is involved in the process. C++ simply does not work this way. Perhaps, in addition to the initial confusion your terminology is also reversed?

Comment: What do you want `get<U>(tuple)` to return if the value of type `T*` turns out not to be a valid `U`? Are we doing a `dynamic_cast` here to check the runtime type? While this is *probably* doable with sufficient amounts of template chicanery, I strongly suspect it to be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) brought on by awkwardly-designed architecture.

Comment: Then my `get<U>` function can return type `T*` then, which would be fine for my purposes.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the behavior you want? Given `my_get<U>`, for any `T *` in the tuple (`T` being any base of `U`), you want to `dynamic_cast` it to `U *`, and if it passes, return the result? Or what? Can you add usage examples?

Comment: No, return type `T*` from `get<U>(tuple)` will be fine.  I can then run a virtual method with the returned type `T*`.

Comment: Then use `get<T*>`. What's the problem?

Comment: What if the tuple contains several base classes of `U`?

Comment: *"return type `T*` ... will be fine"* Ok, but what about the rest of my comment? How do you want select which pointer to return? `dynamic_cast`? `is_base_of`?

Comment: Please use `@username` when replying, otherwise we don't get notifications.

Comment: Thanks.  All the advice above allowed me to come up with a solution.  This was an XY problem, but I'm sure someone out there might one day need the Y solution.

Answer (score 1):

A C++20 draft which seems to be working:

```cpp
template<typename U, typename... Ts>
constexpr auto get(std::tuple<Ts*...> const& tuple) {
    std::array constexpr candidates{std::derived_from<U, Ts>...};
    static_assert(std::ranges::count(candidates, true) == 1);
    return get<std::ranges::equal_range(candidates, false).size()>(tuple);
}
```

For some evil reason, this question is tagged as `c++11` (which I'm not good at) so I tried to backport my idea. Maybe the following version is suboptimal but I hope that it at least works and this much of `constexpr`less horror is enough.

```cpp
/*
Parameters:
    the index of the current tuple type being examined
    whether it fits
    the derived type
    the next remaining tuple type
    other remaining tuple types
*/
template<std::size_t, bool, typename...> struct Helper
{ static auto constexpr value = SIZE_MAX; };
template<std::size_t i, typename U, typename T, typename... Ts>
struct Helper<i, false, U, T, Ts...>
: Helper<i + 1, std::is_base_of<T, U>::value, U, Ts...>
{};
template<std::size_t i, typename U, typename... Ts>
struct Helper<i, true, U, Ts...>
{ static auto constexpr value = i; };
template<std::size_t i, typename U, typename T, typename... Ts>
struct Helper<i, true, U, T, Ts...> {
    static auto constexpr value = i;
    static_assert(
        Helper<i + 1, std::is_base_of<T, U>::value, U, Ts...>::value == SIZE_MAX,
        "ambiguous"
    );
};

template<typename U, typename T, typename... Ts>
auto get(std::tuple<T*, Ts*...> const& tuple)
-> typename std::remove_reference<decltype(std::get<
    Helper<0, std::is_base_of<T, U>::value, U, Ts...>::value
>(tuple))>::type {
    return std::get<
        Helper<0, std::is_base_of<T, U>::value, U, Ts...>::value
    >(tuple);
}
```